# window.onerror get col number

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have javascript errors reporter with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onerror event.

Problem, what javascript files are packed, so on one line can be many errors. Have can get line + cols of error?

Comment: This seems to be a feature that has not yet been implemented on browsers. In the `window.onerror` handler, the fourth argument is not available, and `new Error().stack` doesn't give any information, either.